# How do I iterate through the Attributes of a C# class (.NET 2.0)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, class, .net-2.0

Say I have a class:

```
public class TestClass
{
  public String Str1;
  public String Str2;
  private String Str3;

  public String Str4 { get { return Str3; } }

  public TestClass()
  {
    Str1 = Str2 = Str 3 = "Test String";
  }
}
```

Is there a way (C# .NET 2) to iterate through the Class 'TestClass' and print out public variables and attributes?

Remeber .Net2

Thank you

Comment: Keep in mind that "attributes" is the wrong word here. You should probably say "iterate through the members of a class". "Attribute" has a specific meaning in C#.

Comment: I often wonder too. The term "attributes" for members of a class in UML surely has been around a lot longer. Does Microsoft do such things on purpose, to confuse developers as some kind of "confuse and conquer" strategy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To iterate through public instance properties:

```
Type classType = typeof(TestClass);
foreach(PropertyInfo property in classType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
  Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
}
```

To iterate through public instance fields:

```
Type classType = typeof(TestClass);
foreach(FieldInfo field in classType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
  Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
}
```

If you also want to include non-public properties, add `BindingFlags.NonPublic` to the arguments of `GetProperties` and `GetFields`.

Comment: +1 for being the only person to actually answer the question directly. :P

Answer (score 1):

You can to use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxz4wk15.aspx)

```
TestClass sample = new TestClass();
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | 
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

foreach (FieldInfo f in sample.GetType().GetFields(flags))
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", f.Name, f.GetValue(sample));

foreach (PropertyInfo p in sample.GetType().GetProperties(flags))
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(sample, null));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(VS.71).aspx).

Here is [an article](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/31578) that uses reflection for extensibility.

Answer (score 0):

To get Properties of a Type we will use:

```
Type classType = typeof(TestClass);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = classType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

To get Attributes defined of a Class we will use:

```
Type classType = typeof(TestClass);
object[] attributes = classType.GetCustomAttributes(false);
```

Boolean flag passed is the Inheritance flag, whether to search in inheritance chain or not.

To get attributes of a property we will use:

```
propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);
```

Using Harvard Code given above:

```
Type classType = typeof(TestClass);
object[] classAttributes = classType.GetCustomAttributes(false); 
foreach(PropertyInfo property in classType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
  object[] propertyAttributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(false); 
  Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
}
```